# Is a mutex needed when modifying a global variable in a signal handler

Tags: c, signals, mutex

Is a `mutex` or some kind of synchronization necessary in this situation

```
static int flag;
void sighandler(int sigid)
{
    if (sigid != SIGINT)
        return;
    flag = 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    if (signal(SIGINT, sighandler) == SIG_ERR)
        return -1; /* cannot handle it ? */
    while (flag == 0)
    {
        do_things();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think so. It's the same thread.

Comment: No.  Your handler is invoked asynchronously to the calling thread - and all other threads.  There should be no contention for the global variable. However, this is *only* true if "sighandler()" is the *only* place "flag" is ever modified.  I'd also recommend an explicit 0 (I'm not somebody who believes "fewer characters is more readable"), and declaring it "volatile": `static volatile int flag = 0;`.

Comment: Fewer characters is **less** readable but initializing to zero is not more readable it's superfluous.

Comment: I strongly disagree: just because it's implicit, doesn't mean you shouldn't explicitly state it, too.,  I feel the same way about curly braces around a simple "if" block, for exactly the same reason.

Comment: @paulsm4 I am very happy to hear that I am not the only one interested in the beauty and readability of code, we have to agree to disagree in what for us consitutes good style and that is valid. But we do agree in that style is **very important**.

Comment: Side note: you almost certainly should be using `sigaction(2)` if you care about portability. The behavior of `signal(2)` varies across UNIX versions and is considered obsolescent by now. See the notes on portability on the manpage for `signal(2)`.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves I did read that before but didn't remember why `sigaction` was important. But anyway the question would still be valid if I use `sigaction`. Also, this is not the final implementation, I was actually doing that to let my program reach the cleanup routine to free all allocated memory just to pass `valgrind`'s test. I will however implement a robust and complete signal handler so knowing that is important. I was going to do some reaserch about it because I do remember that `sigaction` was better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a mutex is either unnecessary or inappropriate in a signal handler.

In the single-threaded case, the mutex is unnecessary.  Yes, you'll want your flag to be [`volatile`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1665452/132382), and (for non-trivial access) also [`sig_atomic_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488791/proper-usage-of-volatile-sig-atomic-t).  However, with only one thread interrupting itself, as it were, you don't need the memory fencing semantics a mutex provides.

In the multithreaded case, by contrast, you do have all the concerns of [cache coherency, re-ordering, and variable tearing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15912774/132382) that mutexes allay.  However, **no pthread mutex call is [async-signal-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9512775/132382)**, and thus a mutex cannot be safely manipulated from within a signal handler.  You'll need to find another way to mix [POSIX threads and signals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2575106/132382) in this case.

Answer (score 3):

No, because you are not doing a read-modify-write on `flag`. You should declare `flag` as `volatile static int flag` to prevent the compiler from optimizing away `while (flag == 0)` to `while (1)`.

Comment: [Someone edited your post](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32261918/2) to substantially change your answer, which is a no-no. I rolled back the edit, but I can only agree with what should have been a comment instead of an edit: `sig_atomic_t` is preferred over an `int` because it's guaranteed that reads and writes always see a consistent value.

Comment: Thanks Filipe!  In practice, reading or writing an aligned `int` is atomic on all modern 32 bit processors.

Comment: Yeah, it's more a matter of good practice and code clarity I guess.